# Detect if screensaver is active

Tags: d-bus, screensaver

I want to detect whether the screensaver is active.  On Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora 21, I tried the following command:

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Lock
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
```

I'm probably misunderstanding `dbus-send` as d-feet shows me that the method `GetActive` is available.

[image: d-feet screenshot]

How *can* I detect screensaver activity, preferably in a desktop independent manner? There is a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177286/cross-linux-method-to-detect-screensaver-or-locked-screen-running), which however wasn't solved.

Comment: In my enviroment (KDE 4 on Fedora 21), your dbus-send command starts a screensaver.

Comment: @marbu Interesting! I guess there is something wrong with my command - question is, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't misunderstanding dbus-send.

It's just that [Gnome-Shell is lying](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689225). That means a Gnome-Shell developer literally took the KDE API description as-is and only implemented the 2 methods that are part of the freedesktop [idle inhibition specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/latest/ch03.html). Other methods thus return with  unimplemented error:

```
+        } else if (g_strcmp0 (method_name, "GetActive") == 0) {
+                goto unimplemented;
+        } else ...
```

Review comments that considered this approach being confusing were ignored.

This is still the status quo with Gnome-Shell 3.38.1 (e.g. on Fedora 33):

```
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported
This method is not implemented
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported
This method is not implemented
```

Thus, your best approach is to try multiple methods until you don't get an `NotSupported` error back.

For example to check for Gnome-Shell:

```
$ qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive                
false
```

Comment: Great! I found `gnome-screensaver-command --query` seems to work as well, but it prints a localized textual message which is much less convenient.

Comment: @ThomasW. using `LC_ALL=C gnome-screensaver-command --query` perhaps helps with the localization (haven't tested it as I don't have that command installed)

Comment: Of course it would, but who knows if the wording of the message might be changed at some point? A `true`/`false` value if much better.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your environment:

```
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive

$ qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive

$ qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

The correct one should give a true or false statement. The incorrect one will give an error.

```
$ qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive
false

$ qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
Service 'org.kde.screensaver' does not exist.
```

(I'm running Gnome)

Comment: I'm running Gnome and the Gnome command returns false even when my screensaver is enabled.

Comment: And would you like to mention what version of Gnome?

Comment: With Gnome-Shell 3.38.1, your `org.gnome.ScreenSaver` examples don't work, i.e. I have to use `/org/gnome/ScreenSaver` as second argument instead of `/ScreenSaver`.

Comment: No real surprise that Gnome 3 is different to Gnome 2. I dropped Gnome long ago.

Comment: `qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive` also only returns "Service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' does not exist." with 3.28.3 (RHEL7)