# Dbus Inhibitor added but immediately removed

Tags: d-bus

I've learned that it's possible to create inhibitors for a GUI session via [dbus](https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html#org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibitor.GetFlags). However, when I do try to add an inhibitor, it is immediately removed. Here's an example.

I call to add inhibitor via this command (which is supposed to prevent logout from happening):

```
qdbus org.gnome.SessionManager  /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibit "x-terminal-emulator" $(xdotool getactivewindow) "TEST REASON" 1
```

The output of `dbus-monitor` suggests that it is added, but then immediately removed.

```
$ dbus-monitor --profile | grep -i inhibitor
sig 1474613346.596581   156 :1.23   <none>  /org/gnome/SessionManager   org.gnome.SessionManager    InhibitorAdded
sig 1474613346.603137   159 :1.23   <none>  /org/gnome/SessionManager   org.gnome.SessionManager    InhibitorRemoved
```

How can I troubleshoot this ?

System in use: Ubuntu 16.04, Unity

Comment: @don_crissti yup, seems like it was  exactly that - inhibitor removed once calling process exits. I've created python script which creates the inhibitor and then enters infinite while loop. The inhibitor removed only when i use keyboard interrupt on the script.  Of course this cannot be closed as duplicate , since that question is on different site, but if you want - feel free to write your own answer for this one. I'll accept.  I'll probably will write my own answer also, just to document the python script, but that's only a thought

Comment: @don_crissti I will do that. This question is sort of research . I'm working on another answer  for AskUbuntu site, which requires this solution. Once I have coherent answers for both, I'll post so that everything can be nicely referenced . Thank you again for your help !

Comment: related: [Detect if screensaver is active](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197032/1131)

Answer (score 0):

The inhibitor is immediately removed because it's auto-removed on dbus client disconnect.

Thus, you have to keep your client running for as long as the inhibition should be active.

Example:

```
python3 -c 'import pydbus; pydbus.SessionBus().get(
"org.gnome.SessionManager").Inhibit("what", 0, "why", 1);
import time; time.sleep(2**32-1)'
```

Related for testing is the `IsInhibited` and `GetInhibitors` methods of that `org.gnome.SessionManager` D-Bus interface, e.g.:

```
qdbus org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager \
    org.gnome.SessionManager.IsInhibited 8
```

For how to list the inhibitors cf. [list_inhibitors()](https://github.com/gsauthof/utility/blob/69d569789e62c4a774916235bf57e0c3691cd5b9/inhibit.py#L72-L78) in a utility of mine.